What is the title of this movie
Those days, (about year 2000 forward) I used to watch tv channel, Sri Lanka Rupavahini Corporation (SLRC). They telecast some English language movies of which I don't know the title. Because the movie was dubbed in Sinhala, I cannot say whether it is English or not. One of the movie has to be famous. I remember only two scenes of that movie.
First scene: young boys are lined up in a row and are said to strip their shorts. A priest beats them on their butts.
Second scene: A boy returns home. A maid applies some medication to boy's buttocks.
These two scenes do not appear consecutively. I love this movie. Please provide suggested titles. The year of the movie  could be between year 1950 and 2000.
Please comment if anyone knows the title

50 years is a very, very broad timeframe. Please try to narrow that down as much as possible.

It could be
Un Bon Petit Diable,  1983, France
It has scenes similar to both the ones in the description.
